# Contact MiddleName interferes with FirstName functions in full and partial sandboxes

Tags: soql, contact, full-sandbox

We have Middle Name enabled in production.  In a full sandbox, when we try any standard workflow, Flow Get Records step or SOQL query that involves Contact.FirstName = 'some value', the query/function fails to find any contact if it has a Middle Name value.

> Contact 1 FirstName: Jane, MiddleName: Nancy, Last Name: Smith
>
> Contact 2 FirstName: Jane, MiddleName: null, Last Name: Jones

`SOQL SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Jane'` returns only Contact 2, not Contact 1.

Flow `Get Records step with criteria FirstName = 'Jane' AND LastName = 'Smith'` fails to find Contact 1.

If I use LIKE in SOQL, then the query does work:

`SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Jane%'` returns both contacts.

I have checked the following:

- This problem is not in production, just the full sandbox.
- This problem occurs in the full sandboxes of two different clients.
- There are no hidden Unicode characters.
- If I edit the middle name of an affected contact, the problem remains.
- If I edit the first name of an affected contact, then the problem goes away.
- If I enter a middle name for a contact that started without one, it is not affected.
- If I create a new contact with a middle name, it is not affected.
- Same problem affects partial sandbox

Is anyone else seeing this in their full or partial sandboxes? I've opened a case with Partner support.

Comment: Not seen this and it sounds like a new bug. I do know that [SOQL struggles with middle names](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240351/contacts-with-middlename-values-and-queries) when you try to match the compound ```Name``` field for a Contact but haven't seen this one.